# Change uniform grid after window resize

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a uniform grid in this application. After resizing the window (when `width < 300`) it removes the right column from the grid, and deletes items. After reverting to the previous size (`width > 300`), it adds back the deleted column and its elements.

But in my code I have two global variables `public ObservableCollection<CarType> temp;` and `public bool Crutch;`. How can I improve this?

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Cars cars;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        cars = new Cars();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = cars;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CarType> temp;

    public bool Crutch;
    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSize.Width<300)
        {
            if (cars.Items.Count == 4)
            {
                cars.Columns = 1;
                cars.Rows = 2;
                temp = new ObservableCollection<CarType>(cars.Items);
                cars.Items.RemoveAt(cars.Items.Count - 1);
                cars.Items.RemoveAt(cars.Items.Count - 2);
                Crutch = true;
            }
        }
        if (e.NewSize.Width>300)
        {
            if (Crutch)
            {
                cars.Items = temp;
                cars.Columns = 2;
                cars.Rows = 2;
                Crutch = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class CarType
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
}
public class Cars:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int rows;

    private int columns;
    public int Rows 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.rows;
        }

        set
        {
            this.rows = value;
            RaisePropertyChaged("Rows");
        }
    }
    public int Columns
    {
        get
        {
            return this.columns;
        }

        set
        {
            this.columns = value;
            RaisePropertyChaged("Columns");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CarType> items;
    public ObservableCollection<CarType> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.items;
        }

        set
        {
            this.items = value;
            RaisePropertyChaged("Items");
        }
    }
    public Cars()
    {
        Rows = 2;
        Columns = 2;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<CarType>();
        Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date  =DateTime.Now, number = 1 });
        Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date = DateTime.Now, number = 2 });
        Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date = DateTime.Now, number = 3 });
        Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date = DateTime.Now, number = 4 });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChaged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
}
```

**XAML**

```xaml
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="500" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
    <Canvas>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Columns}" Rows="{Binding Rows}"></UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid Width="200" Height="100">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding number}"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding date}"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding comments}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question title to reflect what the program does, not what you want the review to be about. You could add the note about particularly wanting to avoid global variables to the question itself instead.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be nicer to use a [WrapPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.WrapPanel(v=vs.110).aspx) and play with the [ItemWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.itemwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) instead ?

Also I would suggest watching the size of the actual container instead using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel/1083733#1083733).

Finally, you should really add change validation in your setters to avoid calling RaisePropertyChanged (you have a typo in this one) event when the value hasn't changed:

```
public int Rows 
{ 
    get { return rows; }
    set
    {
        if (rows == value) return;
        rows = value;
        RaisePropertyChaged("Rows");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can also reduce to an embedded single-line statement: `if (rows != (rows = value))  RaisePropertyChaged("Rows");`